# How to open Firefox 7 in safe mode in Windows 7 (64bit)?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

How to open Firefox 7 in safe mode in Windows 7 (64bit)? I have no **Mozilla Firefox->Mozilla Firefox(Safe Mode)** in my start menu and I made a shortcut with this `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -safe-mode` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.  The easiest is to just hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you start Firefox.  The second option is to go to the Firefox menu, select Help and choose "Restart with Add-ons Disabled..."

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode

Comment: I can't go to firefox menu bar because I installed this plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/ but now want to uninstall